# cubic error with volume ID

Tags: xubuntu

I ran cubic and passed the original iso file "xubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso"
but it says "*error: the original volume id is required*"

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you **verified** it being capable of handling ubuntus later than 17 (mentioned on the webpage).

Comment: What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using? What version of Cubic are you using?

Comment: @Hannu, which web page are you referring to?

Comment: Assuming the software mentioned (cubic) is this -> https://ubunlog.com/en/ubuntu-custom-cubic-iso/ -> "Note for Ubuntu 17.10 users:"

Answer (score 0):

I had that error when I tried to place the iso image inside the source-disk folder, it stopped when I just left it inside the project folder. The Volume ID I am trying it on is Xubuntu 22.04.2 LTS amd64